If you get pulled for secondary inspection at immigration, missing flight, will the airline rebook you?
M. A has a single, international-to-domestic ticket.
They however get pulled into a further secondary inspection, which makes them miss their flight, but is ultimately admitted.
Does the airline have to accommodate and rebook or can they treat it as a delay of your fault and strand you?

The airline doesn't have to find that the delay was the traveler's fault. All the airline must do is assert that it is not responsible for any country's immigration procedures and after-landing delays. I'd expect the airline's T&Cs would cover this.

I'm pretty sure they try to keep this as vague as possible (in their favour) but I expect that most airlines would rebook the passenger on the following flight in that situation.

@jcaron They might indeed. I was staggered earlier this spring when, after missing an international departure from SFO — my fault for not paying attention to the flight's change in departure time — my partner and I were rebooked on the next day's flight, same class of service, at no cost. Could have knocked me over with a feather.

Related:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2312/4171,  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185630/4171,  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73906/4171, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67142/4171

They often ask you to be in the airport 3 hours in advance. I think in this case being in the airport before or after this threshold might affect the airline's decision to re-book you or not.

I suggest specifying in more detail what "secondary" means, also to make this question easier to search.

@André This wouldn't have anything to do with when you arrived at the departure airport.

They don't have to but in most cases they will. It depends a bit on the mood of the people on the ground and your negotiation skills.

Really, it can be argued they have to: they are the ones who suggested the given itinerary, they should take into account how long it takes to go through immigration, and not just averages but also cases when there are long queues or the passenger gets sent to secondary. They will probably have language in their terms to protect them, but in many cases the law is going to be on the passenger's side.

@jcaron I know a German couple (white and unflashy), who were held by immigration while transiting London Heathrow on their way from Germany to USA and accused of child trafficking, just because the father's surname didn't match with the children. They missed their onward flight, the airline cancelled the rest of their ticket and they had to buy new tickets London - USA - Germany to complete their holiday trip. I am not sure which airline they were flying with, but with that itinerary it must probably have been BA.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Held by immigration transiting in LHR from DE to US? That probably wasn't on a single ticket...

@jcaron .. "it can be argued they have to" .. how?  "in many cases the law is going to be on the passenger's side"  that's not true at all (unfortnately).  what country were you thinking of?

"in many cases they will" unfortunately I think that may be basically out of date :/ a thought from a more genteel age of air travel, when you could get an upgrade by wearing a nice suit, and your kids could visit the cockpit.

Note that the OP is talking about international-departing flights (I think).  It would be pretty rare to keep 500 passengers, sitting in the fueled plane waiting for takeoff, to wait for someone who's a sluggard (regardless if it is "not their fault" morally or something).

@Fattie the OP is talking about international-to-domestic, and about rebooking on the next flight, not making the plane wait.

I never went in secondary, but once I have huge immigration queue on US immigration border, so I missed the domestic flight.
I went to the gate, and staff told me they automatically rebooked me on the next flight. No need to discuss with them. I do not know if it was an airline policy, or if things have changed since them.
I think you should tell the staff about your next flight, so they can advice airline in time (but it will not work well on getting things quick). That queue seems never moving (from one person which had problem with fingerprint reader).
BTW it was around 10 years ago. For sure before COVID.

This was pure luck, unfortunately, Giacomo. Unfortunately this answer is misleading.  The very simple answer is "No, they do not have to"

@Fattie: why not? Do you have negative examples? The error was on airline: they sold a single ticket which cannot be fulfilled, so a commercially deceptive practice if they will not fulfill the contract.

It would be helpful if this answer could include a rough date for the experience described (in response to @Fattie’s suggestion that this sort of optimism is out of date).

@GiacomoCatenazzi The question posits a situation where the delay was due directly to the immigration status of the passenger. As an extreme example, a passenger gets caught smuggling drugs, is detained, serves 2 years in jail, is it the airline's "error"?

@user71659: I'm not sure about that. I didn't read the answer in such manner. As I wrote, one in my group got pulled and put in a special room with a lot more people, just because the fingerprint machine could not take fingerprints (nervous flyer). Just end 2019 I got pulled from custom in a secondary room (more people there) to an additional custom control. Both cases just caused delay, nothing particular was checked. I have no idea the reason OP was pulled for an additional check.

@user71659 If a traveller is smuggling it's the travellers own fault; it's something the traveller has control over. Being pulled aside for secondary inspection is outside your control.

To add another point, I had a similar (positive) experience around 2010 - lost connection due to immigration queue from Madrid to Newark, rebooked (just by asking nicely) in the waiting list for Austin (I think, not sure... Ages ago)  and embarked.

@vidarlo An almost opposite example, suppose the fingerprint scanner has to restart and takes an extra 60 seconds, but you were running so late that that causes you to miss your departure by 30 seconds. You were running late because of some traffic accident right outside the airport (unavoidable). None of this is your "fault", except it IS your job to get there with enough time, you have control over that by getting there earlier or booking a longer connection.

Compare to the recent Cloud Strike outage where airlines are fighting tooth and nail to avoid paying, because it was the airport's computer having problems, not the airline's. (Which personally I think airlines should be on the hook for that one, but not for the occasional person who didn't plan properly.)

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess this wasn't RyanAir? :)  That's a perk of a full-service airline.

@user3067860: "it IS your job to get there with enough time" - the situation asked about is that you have arrived at the airport by (international) flight. If you were in time for that, anything external that actually prevented you from making the connection at the intermediate airport is outside of your control.

I would strongly recommend not counting on a rebooking or any guaranteed compensation of any kind. The likelihood of it happening would probably depend greatly on the airline's overall reputation for service in general. For instance, a poor-quality or cheap carrier I would expect would fight a rebooking as much as possible.
On the other end of the spectrum are carriers known for their good service. A personal experience is that a family member of mine always gets stopped at US Customs for secondary screening when arriving on Air New Zealand. Usually it's not a big issue, but this time we already had a short connection and a delay on the Air New Zealand flight, plus an Emirates A380 dumped their entire load of 500+ passengers in the Customs line at once.
Even some passengers who didn't get stopped (only delayed by the line) in Customs were missing their connections, so when we get to the rebooking counter the agent was automatically offering everyone a rebooking, plus a hotel stay and a very generous dinner and breakfast allowance. We ended up not being out any cost for the situation. I wouldn't have trusted United or American to do the same if the booking had been through them, and I'm sure Delta would offer the rebooking but might not offer a similar hotel/food compensation.
TLDR: If you're booking on an carrier known for poor service, you're probably not going to see any compensation. If you're booking on a carrier known for their good service (like AirNZ) and/or there's a delay involved, there's a good chance they'll be offering it without you even asking, especially if you're not the only person missing the connection. In our case there were at least 12 of us from multiple parties who missed connections from our flight.

(U)LCC never offer single ticket connexions so that is not that relevant to my question

Many non-US airlines explicitly disclaim liability for passenger delays due to security/immigration issues, and so will NOT re-book you for free unless you get an exceptionally nice handling staffer willing and able to bend the rules without risking their job.

Even if this answer is correct for some parts of the world, it's most definitely not for other parts.  eg, every single US carrier will rebook for in this situation.

@Doc Thanks, edited
